# AWS SSL Installed but not working

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just got commodo free ssl trial, and uploaded the ssl to my EC2 instance using AWS CLI, then changed the listener in the loadbalancer to the new ssl, but when I run ssl checker still shows the previous self signed certificate, which causes the browser warning when accessing the website, I have googled for hours trying to find and answer and followed everything in regards of updating the SSL but still no luck

Comment: You can try AWS ACM. For more: https://medium.com/@nipunr/free-ssl-aws-route53-acm-188ae3f66fed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I had to figure it out myself, since it was the first time i had to install an SSL on an aws server, and thought i would post the answer in case someone else is going trough the same issue.

I have got my ssl from comodo which they provide 2 files (file.crt & file.ca-bundle), I went through load balancer to change my SSL first, not 100% sure if it is a required step, but I would recommend doing, so you would need the three ssl files (name.key "which is the one you submitted to your ssl provider", name.crt and name.ca-bundle).

1- in my case I was using an ubuntu instance with apache2, you will need to create a new ssl directory in /etc/apache2 (e.g /etc/apache2/ssl).
2- Upload all three files to the new directory.
3- navigate to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled -> and edit ssl-enabled.conf as follows:

```html
<VirtualHost>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html2
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

4- Restart your apache2 service and you should be all good to go.

Hope that was helpful

Comment: Hi, I hit some problems with installing Comodo certificate as well. So what is the DigiCertCA.crt file? is it renamed  file.ca-bundle?